# Tikz node newline for every word

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I create nodes such that every word in a node gets put to a new line?
MWE:

```
\usepackage{tikz} % used instead of adt_web.sty here
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.multipart} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                every node/.style = {
                draw, 
                fill = gray!10,
                shape = rectangle, 
                rounded corners,
                text width = ,
                thick}
            ]
            
            %Nodes
                \node[] (n1) {Some text};
                \node[] (n2) at ($(n1) + (9,0)$) {Some more text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I want is dynamically-sized multi-line nodes without hyphenated text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If solution, which require that you manually break a text line, ¸is ok to you, than the simple(st) solution can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm,
every node/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners, fill = gray!10,
                     align=flush left},  % <---
                    ]
%Nodes
\node (n1) {Some \\ text};
\node (n2) [right=of n1]    {Some more \\ text};
\node (n3) [right=of n2]    {Some \\ more \\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you expect, that this should be done automatically, than solution is not so simple anymore. For such solution you'll have to wait for LaTeX guru, which will write a macro, which each empty space in text replace with `\\`  ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % used instead of adt_web.sty here
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.multipart}

\newcommand{\split}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {
    draw, 
    fill = gray!10,
    shape = rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    thick
  },
]
%Nodes
\node[] (n1) {\split{Some \\ text}};
\node[] (n2) at ($(n1) + (4.5,0)$) {\split{Some more \\ text}};
\node[] (n2) at ($(n1) + (9,0)$) {\split{Some \\ more \\ text}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]